# Kibana visualisation linear chart where x is time and Y is my field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

My problem is that i don't know how to create a visualisation in Kibana 4.4.1 by field. I already have logs indexed. I search this log by pathname and each log have fields that I need. My fields has named `EACH.Algorithm`, `EACH.TotalCount`. I want to create a visualisation with linear chart where `X` is time (when logs coming to logstash) and `Y` shows number from `EACH.TotalCount` in time. Each visualsation are for only one `EACH.Algorithm`.

This image shows what i expect.
[image]

As you see in `TIME` i put value of `EACH.TotalCount`. Each chart is for only one algorithm.
Actually I can get linear chart but from `unique count` by `EACH.TotalCount`. It's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you'll need to get your data into elasticsearch via logstash.  If you don't know how to do that, clarify your question.

I've simulated your data with the following script:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/logstash
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/logstash/data -d '{
    "@timestamp": "2016-02-26T08:32:00-0600",
    "algorithm": "xxx",
    "totalCount": 1000
}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/logstash/data -d '{
    "@timestamp": "2016-02-26T08:32:08-0600",
    "algorithm": "xxx",
    "totalCount": 1500
}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/logstash/data -d '{
    "@timestamp": "2016-02-26T08:32:09-0600",
    "algorithm": "xxx",
    "totalCount": 546
}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/logstash/data -d '{
    "@timestamp": "2016-02-26T08:32:10-0600",
    "algorithm": "xxx",
    "totalCount": 500
}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/logstash/data -d '{
    "@timestamp": "2016-02-26T08:32:11-0600",
    "algorithm": "xxx",
    "totalCount": 1500
}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/logstash/data -d '{
    "@timestamp": "2016-02-26T08:32:12-0600",
    "algorithm": "yyy",
    "totalCount": 500
}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/logstash/data -d '{
    "@timestamp": "2016-02-26T08:32:13-0600",
    "algorithm": "yyy",
    "totalCount": 1000
}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/logstash/data -d '{
    "@timestamp": "2016-02-26T08:32:14-0600",
    "algorithm": "yyy",
    "totalCount": 1465
}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/logstash/data -d '{
    "@timestamp": "2016-02-26T08:32:15-0600",
    "algorithm": "yyy",
    "totalCount": 412
}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/logstash/data -d '{
    "@timestamp": "2016-02-26T08:32:16-0600",
    "algorithm": "yyy",
    "totalCount": 354
}'
```

So now we need to build the visualization.  Go into the visualize section and create a new line chart.  Then select the following options:

- On the Y-Axis

  - select `sum` of `totalCount` field
- On the X-Axis

  - select `Split Chart`
  - select `Terms`
  - select `Field` of `algorithm.raw` (logstash should create that field for you)
  - Hit the `Add sub-buckets` at the bottom
  - select `Date Histogram`
  - select `Field` of `@timestamp`
  - select `Interval` of `second`

You will end up with something like this:

[image]

And your visualization will look like this:

[image]

If you want the curved lines like in your image, go over to the `options` tab and select `smooth lines`.

Comment: Woow nice :) It looks now much better. But i have a question. Why i must check `Sum`? I think Max or average is usefull ?

Comment: You can use any function you want. Min max or average. Whichever makes sense to summarize over a large interval.

Comment: Thanks :) There's any way to share my dashboard without authorization ? I'm trying do it with `<iframe>` but it require credentials.

Comment: That's out of scope of the original question. But no, if there is with on kinsman, it'll be required in an Iframe